# Guava EventBus and Singleton: Synchronization

Tags: android, synchronization, guava, android-guava

I have a question regarding the principle of work of Guava EventBus. My objects are registered to EventBus. In 10 second time interval, message is sent to them, where processing is done and I compare some variable in object with singleton value.By some criteria, I change singleton value. I made some research in Guava documentation but I didn't find any information about synchronization issues.

Is this right way to do so?

With regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use `EventBus` (rather than `AsyncEventBus`), there are no synchronization issues *added* by the bus. The event bus simply executes you subscribers immediately in the same thread.

As long as you yourself stick with a single thread, there's no multithreading and no need for any synchronization.

Comment: Thanks, you "deleted" all my doubts :)

Answer (score 1):

## EventBus Is Built For Concurrent Use

From the [EventBus source code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.java), line 91:

> This class is safe for concurrent use.

I too was concerned about concurrency because the doc makes no mention. After perusing the source code, seeing this comment plus the use of concurrent collections has erased my concerns.

## `volatile`

Regarding the Question's mention of comparing to a singleton's changing value across threads, you may need to use the `volatile` keyword to protect access, to guarantee visibility of current value rather than old value cached in a processor core. But that is a regular concurrency concern, unrelated to use of the EventBus.